# Inscribe a triangle in the given triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In a given triangle ABC inscribe the triangle A'B'C' whose sides are parallel with three given lines p ,q ,r ( lines are given as sides of a triangle).

Comment: Join midpoints of the sides.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about geometry of a triangle? Try to improve your question

Comment: This problem is in topic of homothety.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Assume you need to inscribe in the triangle $ABC$ a triangle with lines parallel to the sides of the triangle $EDF$ (see figure).

Draw through the vertices of $\triangle EDF$ lines parallel to the sides of $\triangle ABC$. Be careful: combine the lines and vertices in such a way that the lines are outside of $\triangle EDF$. Find the intersections of these three lines and name them $A',B',C'$, respectively. Draw the lines $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$. They will intersect in a common point $O$.

Can you complete the solution?

[image]